# RMI over SSL - Slow communication

Tags: java, performance, ssl, virtual-machine, rmi

I have created a test program between two virtual machines on my computer. So I have an RMI Server running on a virtual machine on VMware and I have an RMI Client running on another virtual machine on VMware.

I have set up SSL using `SslRMIServerSocketFactory` and `SslRMIClientSocketFactory` and it is possible to call methods from the client to the server, having the server to respond with the return value. So right now I have two Ubuntu machines running on VMware.

What happens is that the client makes the call to the server and I have to wait for about 17 seconds until the response from the server reaches the client and the print is executed on console. **Updated**: The method's call is fast. All this time is taken by the `Registry.lookup()` function.

Aren't 17 seconds too much time?
I know that VMs are slow by nature, plus the fact that SSL is running but still, aren't 17 seconds too much for what I am doing? The remote method only adds two integers and returns the result.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but more of a debugging step.  Have you tried your calculation outside of ssl?  Historically, RMI has always been slow and one of the reasons people have moved to lighter transfer methods, like json.  Now, I do not know if RMI has been sped up in the last 15 years or not, but I do not hear chattter of 'oh, json?  That is so slow, we moved to RMI...'

Comment: RMI without SSL worked fine. Only a few miliseconds to get the return value of the remote called method. That is why I was asking if it is normal that the introduction of SSL could have caused all this delay.

Comment: So, I did a bit of google-fu on your question.  Please check this answer and see if it helps you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343132/rmi-responding-very-slow  You can also turn on the ssl debug option for java to see if anything is obvious there.  To turn on ssl debugging add -Djavax.net.debug=ssl to your applications vm options.

Comment: I saw that answer before asking this question. I already had the hostname property defined on the server. I have put the IP address of the server. It turns out it is the `Registry.lookup()` call that is taking all this time... remote method calls are fast. Although the slow down only takes place at the beggining, I would like to know if this is normal or not. And if it isn't, how to avoid this.

Comment: Are you using SSL to the Registry?

Comment: Yes I am. In fact my implementation is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320874/rmi-with-ssl-handshake-exception-no-cipher-suites-in-common-when-server-star). Now that you mention, is there a way to verify the correctness and working of the SSL communication? I used my host to capture the traffic of the virtual machines using Wireshark. I capture TCP and RMI packets. I recognized a TCP PUSH message containing keystore information such as the Organization, Location and Country, so my guess is that it is working.

Comment: You would know straight away if it wasn't working. I suspect you have a DNS problem. Can you change your lookup string to use an IP address instead of a hostname, and see if that makes it better? Or worse?

Comment: I had "Compute" as the lookup name. I set it to "//192.168.190.129/Compute" and to "//ubuntu/Compute", tested and the result is the same. The registry port is 1099 so I can ommit the port according to the documentation.

Comment: OK. It could still be a DNS problem, e.g. reverse DNS lookup. Can you run the server JVM with `-Djava.rmi.server.logCalls=true` and `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` and observe the lookup? If it's DNS, the 17 second delay will happen before the server JVM console prints anything. NB I don't see how you could possibly have had `"Compute"` as the lookup name if you are running between two virtual machines. You could have had it as the *`bind()`* name, but that's not what we were talking about.

Comment: The "Compute" worked fine, the `rebind()` function which is the one I used also had "Compute" as a parameter. So I started the server and this was the output http://pastebin.com/sxYRU0gz. This output started appearing as soon as I run the server. Then, on the client, I started it and only after ~17 seconds this was printed on the SERVER console: http://pastebin.com/Xf6swmj9

Comment: I'm talking about the *`lookup()`* string. Not the `bind()` string. Change the *`lookup()`* string to an IP address. You cannot possibly have had that as just `"Compute"`.

Comment: From what I understood, I have to bind the Server with a name, then use `lookup()` with the same name to get the Server reference on the Client, right? So both of the strings need to be equal. I tried putting the name as "192.168.190.129" and it takes all those seconds to display the result on the Client console. Please correct me if I am not correct in what I said.

Comment: The *path part of the URL* has to be equal. On the server you can just use `bind("Compute")` because it assumes `//localhost:1099/`, which is correct for the server because the registry is in the same host. On the client you have to specify the hostname at least, unless you're running the client on the server host. So, for the third time, change the lookup string to use an IP address instead of a hostname.

Comment: I have already bound the Server as `"Compute"` and, on the Client (which is on a different VM) I lookup for `"//192.168.190.129:1099/Compute"` and I get a `java.rmi.NotBoundException`.

Comment: Sorry, just looked at your code again. You're using `Registry.lookup()` so it's just a name, not a URL. You need to use an IP address instead of a hostname in the `getRegistry()` call, i.e. as the command line argument of your client.

Comment: I always used this command to run the Client: `java -cp /home/f4e/src:/home/f4e/public_html/classes/compute.jar JavaMainClient 192.168.190.129 90 80`. The 90 and 80 are the numbers that I want the remote method to add.

Comment: I actually edited mine aswell: I always used this command to run the Client: `java -cp /home/f4e/src:/home/f4e/public_html/classes/compute.jar JavaMainClient 192.168.190.129 90 80`. The 90 and 80 are the numbers that I want the remote method to add.

Comment: OK well I still think it's DNS, probably reverse DNS. Do you have `192.168.190.129` in the `/etc/hosts` file of the client? If not, put it in, with an alias, and remeasure. You could also try setting `-Dsun.rmi.client.logCalls=true` at the client JVM to see when exactly it starts doing RMI.

Comment: Ok, so my **Server** /etc/hosts has: `127.0.0.1 localhost` and `192.168.190.129 ubuntu`. Now, I tried to bind `"//192.168.190.129/Compute"` and lookup using `192.168.190.129` with the name `"Compute"` and this Connection Refused Exception occurred: http://pastebin.com/zAgkxZew. Can this be related?

Comment: 'Connection refused' to a correct IP address means you didn't start the Registry or the server, or both. But I don't know why you're now using IP addresses in the lookup or bind strings when I've just told you not to, because you're using Registry, where they aren't URLs. Just use `"Compute"`.

Comment: I added `192.168.190.129 ubuntu` (`ubuntu` is unique in the file) and run the client with that parameter. So, I run it, after a few **seconds** this appeared: `Oct 14, 2014 5:52:40 PM sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef logClientCall
FINER: main: outbound call: [endpoint:[192.168.190.129:1099,javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory@13b3d473](remote),objID:[0:0:0, 0]] : sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub[0:0:0, 0]: java.rmi.Remote lookup(java.lang.String)`. And after 10 seconds this appeared: http://pastebin.com/iT6kzR2e. 170 is the add result printed. (I made 2 calcs on the Client but only print one)

Comment: OK now can I have the log printed by `-Djava.rmi.server.logCalls=true`. You only posted part of it before. Don't want to see the SSL log.

Comment: Using that parameter on the server, here is the output: http://pastebin.com/N1BsSEaw. The entry at 3:32:31 is when I run the server. Then I run the client and after ~17 seconds, the remaining log was printed. Note: the IP Address of the client now is 192.168.190.140. The server's ip address remained the same.

Comment: OK now can you check whether the server's `/etc/hosts` file has an entry for the client IP. And if not, put one in?

Comment: Done that. Now, apparently, it takes ~1 second for the server to return the added value. Configuring it this way makes it work! But I don't understand how this makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does reverse DNS when it either connects or accepts a socket, for security purposes. You didn't have any DNS or reverse DNS information about the server available at the client, or about the client available at the server. Putting a server entry into the client's `/etc/hosts` file and a client entry into the server's `/etc/hosts` file fixed that. Otherwise it would try via a DNS server and timeout waiting for a response before proceeding.

Comment: Well, what if the client IP changes, or I have new clients? Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Doing it in `/etc/hosts` is only a workaround of course, you should do it directly in the network DNS somehow. How is platform-dependent.

Comment: What I meant is: isn't there a way to prevent Java from reverse-DNSing ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: I had the same problem connecting my RMI client to the RMI server on the same machine. In my case even the instantiation of an object inheriting from UnicastRemoteObject in the server caused a delay of more than 20 secs. Configuring /etc/hosts with localhost didn't fix the problem and I had to use this line in my java application before using RMI:

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem connecting my RMI client to the RMI server on the same machine. 
In my case even the instantiation of an object inheriting from *UnicastRemoteObject* in the server caused a delay of more than 20 secs. Configuring /etc/hosts with localhost didn't fix the problem and I had to use this line in my java application before using RMI:

```
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "127.0.0.1");
```